# Как в С++ передать функцию в качестве параметра?

Tags: c++, функции

Как там все это объявить и после получить возвращаемое значение?

Comment: Почитайте про Callback functions, вот здесь, например, тыц: [Callback (программирование)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)).

Comment: Опишите поподробней, что нужно.

Answer (score 12):

Функция:

```
int MyFunction(int a){ printf("Hi!\n");   return 2*a; }
```

Объявляем:

```
int (*pt2Func)(int ) = NULL;
```

Инициализируем указатель:

```
pt2Func = &MyFunction;
```

Передаем в функцию и используем:

```
void PassPointer(int (*pt2Func)(int )) {
   int result = (*pt2Func)(12); 
   cout << result << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Просто несколько примеров

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int xx (char *s, int a)
{
  cout <<"xx-args: "<<s<<", "<<a<<'\n';
  return a+a;
}

int yy (char *s, int a)
{
  cout <<"yy-args: "<<s<<", "<<a<<'\n';
  return a*a;
}

int call (char *s, int a, int (*f)(char *, int))
{
  cout <<"call "<<s<<" "<<a<<" f() = "<<f(s,a)<<'\n';
}

int main ()
{
  int (*x)(char *s, int a);

  x = xx;
  cout << "(*x)()=xx() = "<<x("a+a",3)<<'\n';
  x = yy;
  cout << "(*x)()=yy() = "<<x("a+a",3)<<'\n';
  call("call xx a+a",3,xx);
  call("call yy a*a",3,yy);
}

c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ g++ tfuncall.cpp
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ ./a
xx-args: a+a, 3
(*x)()=xx() = 6
yy-args: a+a, 3
(*x)()=yy() = 9
xx-args: call xx a+a, 3
call call xx a+a 3 f() = 6
yy-args: call yy a*a, 3
call call yy a*a 3 f() = 9
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $
```

Comment: @avp, А почему сначала функция вызывается и выводится её сообщение, а потом уже остальное, хотя функция не на первом месте стоит? То есть почему сначала выводится это "xx-args: a+a, 3", а потом это "(*x)()=xx() = 6". Пытался посмотреть как это реализовано в стандартной библиотеке, но что-то я не нашел iostream в MVC 2010.

Comment: @mzarb, если заменить `cout` на `printf()`, то будет понятно.

    int xx (char *s, int a) {
       printf ("xx-args: %s, %d\n", s, a);
       return a+a;
    }

и в main() 

    x = xx;
    printf ("(*x)()=xx() = %d\n", x("a+a",3));

в main в printf() передается результат вызова x(). При вызове x() отрабатывает printf() в ней, а она возвращает число 6.

Поэтому сначала напечатается printf ("xx-args: %s, %d\n", "a+a", 3);

а уже потом printf ("(*x)()=xx() = %d\n", 6);

С cout аналогично, сначала вычисляются операнды (или как они там называются), а потом их значения выводятся в поток.

Answer (score 7):

```
typedef int (*func)(int a, int b);

int call_func(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

void function(int a, int b, func f)
{
    int sum = f(a, b);
    std::cout << "Sum = " << sum << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
 function(5, 2, &call_func);
}
```

А дальше ищи доку по указателям на функции.

Answer (score 7):

С помощью `boost::function` [так](http://liveworkspace.org/code/9d68d5501710e78870924778678c7d4e). Или `std::function` в С++11 [так](http://liveworkspace.org/code/9d68d5501710e78870924778678c7d4e).
Способ с голыми указателями также применим, но у функциональных объектов возможностей гораздо больше.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

typedef boost::function<int (std::string const&)> MyFunc;

void bar(MyFunc const& func)
{
   func("blabla");
}

int f1(std::string const& str)
{
   std::cout <<"f1 "<<str<<std::endl;
   return 42;
}

int f2(std::string const& str)
{
   std::cout <<"f2 "<<str<<std::endl;
   return 1488;
}

int main()
{
   bar(f1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//Функция
string gold()
{
    return "gold\n";
}

//Фунция принимающая ссылку на фунцию как аргумент
void startFunc(string (&func)()) {
    cout << func();
}

int main()
{
    //Передаём ссылку на функцию Gold как параметр фунции startFunc
    startFunc(gold);

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Добавьте разъяснение к вашему ответу.

Answer (score 1):

Имя функции - ее адрес. Для объявления типа копайте в сторону typedef.
Можно еще [почитать](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120396/)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать шаблон, чтобы иметь возможность задавать функцию по-разному: как в виде функции, так и в виде класса-функтора.

```
// возвращает f(0) + f(1) + ... + f(9)
template <class Func> int sum (Func f)
{
    int res = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        res += f(x);
    return res;
}
```

Теперь можно вызвать `sum(g)`, где

```
int g(int x) { return 2 * x; }
```

так и `sum(h)`, где

```
class h {
public:
    int operator()(int x) { return 2 * x; }
};
```

Вызов:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << sum(g) << " " << sum(h());
    
    return 0;
}
```